# C# Saving image from picturebox (A generic error occurred in GDI+)

Tags: c#, generics, picturebox

First of all im retrieving the image and fill the picturebox from Access Database with this.

```
            con.Open();
        string sql = "select Foto from TSP_Data where KayitNo=" + sNo;
        OleDbCommand cmdResim = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
        using (OleDbDataReader oku = cmdResim.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (oku.Read())
            {
                byte[] veri = oku["Foto"] as byte[];
                using (MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    mstream.Write(veri, 0, veri.Length);
                    Image fotop = Image.FromStream(mstream);
                    digerFormFoto.Image = fotop;
                }
            }
        }
```

> there is nothing wrong with the retrieving image to picturebox without error , it works fine.

but when i try to save the image with picturebox save method with savefiledialog it gives error like :
**A generic error occurred in GDI+**

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "Images|*.png;*.bmp;*.jpg";
        ImageFormat format = ImageFormat.Png;
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(sfd.FileName);
            switch (ext)
            {
                case ".jpg":
                    format = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
                    break;
                case ".bmp":
                    format = ImageFormat.Bmp;
                    break;
                case ".png":
                    format = ImageFormat.Png;
                    break;
            }
            digerFormFoto.Image.Save(sfd.FileName, format); //digerFormFoto is picturebox
```

Comment: What if you try and save image without specifying a format?

Answer (score 2):

This may occur if the Image is already in use by GDI+ or not being disposed previously because GDI+ locks an image when used. I would suggest you to recreate the image with memory stream or either create a new bitmap from picture box and then save it as below:

```
Bitmap bitmapImage = new Bitmap(digerFormFoto.Image);
bitmapImage.Save(sfd.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
```